# Dompdf pictures from mobile devices not in right orientation (Laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, dompdf

If I use a Input field with the camera capture attribute and then add the pictures to dompdf, then the pictures won't be in the right orientation.

If the picture is taken in landscape mode, the picture is turned 180 degrees.

And otherwise 90 degrees.

Google Chrome seems automatically turning the pictures in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the Intervention library with laravel.

Intervention is able to orientate the picture the right way.

Example from http://image.intervention.io/api/orientate

```php
// instantiate image with auto-orientation
$img = Image::make('foo.jpg')->orientate();
```